# Intranet site on .NET 4.0, Windows Server 2003, not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I will start out by saying what will be obvious as you read on, I am not a programmer. That said, I have been tasked by the powers that be to get an accounting intranet site built on Windows Server 2003, ASP.NET 4.0, IIS6, working in IE11.
I have a test enviro set up and have been researching for a few weeks now and have tried (to the best of my limited ability) the different fixes that are out there, including MS patches for .NET and replacing the .browser files as below:
http://www.telerik.com/blogs/how-to-get-your-asp.net-application-working-in-ie11
After following any tips I can find I still end up with the same errors:
!https://www.dropbox.com/s/6qkvbczd6mcnz71/2.jpg?dl=0
The site does work to an extent, when the first row is selected it takes you to the proper form but then after returning to the list and trying to access any other row it returns an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error page.
My next steps will be to try an in place upgrade of the server or to migrate the site to another server, but I only need to keep this site limping along for another year until a move to a different accounting system takes place so I'd rather band-aid it if possible.
I will be most appreciative for any guidance or advice and am more than willing to post any page code or details requested by anyone kind enough to offer their thoughts.
Thanks for reading!

Comment: Do you know how to set breakpoints/debug?  If you do, find where the exception is being thrown and post the code that 'broke' along with the error.

Comment: The errors in the Chrome are JavaScript (client side) errors.  The "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." is happening on the server side.  Do you have access to the source code?  If so you should provide us the snippets of code around the line numbers indicated in the error messages.